# Accessing user details after logging in with Java EE Form authentication

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbcrealm, form-authentication

I have implemented a Java EE security realm that redirects users to login.jsp if they try and access a protected resource.

- Say a user wants to go to a protected url - `http://mywebapp/shopping_cart` which is mapped to ShoppingCartServlet
- As they are not logged in Glassfish directs them to login.jsp
- They then enter their username and password and click Login and the information gets POSTed to `http://mywebapp/j_security_check`
- If they have entered the correct details they are then redirected to the servlet that handles the url `http://mywebapp/shopping_cart`

Now I want to pull the user's details from the database but how can I when there are no parameters in the redirect request?

Their username was sent to `http://mywebapp/j_security_check` but there are no parameters in the redirect request that j_security_check makes to `http://mywebapp/shopping_cart`. So what method is used to access the user's details once they log in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which checks if the user is logged in while no associated `User` object from the database is present in the session. Then, just load that data and put in session.

Basically,

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class UserFilter implements Filter {

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();

        if (remoteUser != null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
                User user = service.find(remoteUser);
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // ...
}
```