# How to trigger Bean after j_security_check complete authentication in Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, j-security-check

I'm quite new to java web page environment. Recently I try to develop an E-Business platform by using Java.

Hence, I'm using j_security_check Form-Based as my authentication tool. It was successfully to re-direct to desire page after authentication completed.

However, due to I have to load end user setting and information from Database (MS SQL 2005), so I have to load all the information after authentication completed and before page re-direct.

I had tried some method by using primefaces but it was unable to trigger the bean method that load user information.

One of the methods that I tried is using oncomplete to trigger the bean method

```
<h:form id="login" prependId="false"
                    onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                        <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username:" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}"   
                                     id="j_username" required="true" label="j_username" />
                        <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:" />  
                        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"   
                                       id="j_password" required="true" label="j_password" />
                        <f:facet name="footer">  
                            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" type="submit" ajax="false"                                                 
                                              oncomplete="#{loginBean.login()}"/>
                        </f:facet>  
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
```

I also been tried something similar to this which just change oncomplete to onclick and others. End up doesn't has any method is workable.

Hence, I hope that anyone of you can give me advise how should I overcome this problem.

Million thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions for this.

1. Create a servlet filter which checks the remote user and the presence of `User` entity in the session. If the remote user is not `null`, but the `User` entity is, then load it from the DB and set it in session. This is concretely answered here: [Accessing user details after logging in with Java EE Form authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758429/accessing-user-details-after-logging-in-with-java-ee-form-authentication/14758549#14758549)
2. Perform lazy loading in the getter of a session scoped bean which should return the `User` entity. This is concretely answered in 1st part of this answer: [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)
3. Perform programmatic login using a real JSF bean action method and obtain the `User` entity directly. This is concretely answered in 2nd part of this answer: [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you should be using `<form action="j_security_check" method="post">` instead of a `<h:form prependId="false">`. Then you also don't need that nasty JS hack to change the form's action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for so long only reply on your answer. I tried the 1st solution that you had suggested but it can't work for me. I added a new class as UserFilter and by using debug mode (NetBean IDE 7.2 i'm using) program couldn't fall into the UserFilter. Is it i missed out something to add so that the program will go for UserFilter after user logged in? Besides, UserService is a method that using to retrieve the user setting that i wish to obtain. isn't? appreciate much for your help..thanks..

Comment: The `@WebFilter` annotation works only on webapps deployed to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` file. Otherwise, you've to register it manually in `web.xml`.

Comment: End up i also not able to fall into WebFilter. Hence i go for method 3 that proposed by @BalusC. It was a great answer that has solved my issue easily..Thanks a lot BalusC...

Comment: sorry for i can't vote this answer as useful answer is because my reputation is not enough to vote...anyway this answer is very useful..thanks..